# How do I correctly define the SelectArg in a raw query?

Tags: android, case, where-clause, ormlite

I need to implement a CASE in the WHERE condition of my query.
I wrote the following code:

```
QueryBuilder<Cars, String> carsQB = carsDao.queryBuilder();
carsQB.selectColumns("id");
carsQB.join(modelsDao.queryBuilder());                          

carsQB.where().raw("CASE WHEN future = true THEN date > ? ELSE endDate > ? END",
    new SelectArg("date"), new SelectArg("endDate"));
```

But I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(4599): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
       Either the column name or SqlType must be set on each argument
```

Both date and endDate are Date columns in my database.

What am I missing? Is there a better way to accomplish this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that (unfortunately) calling `new SelectArg(String)` calls the [`SelectArg(Object) constructor`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/SelectArg.html#SelectArg%28java.lang.Object%29) which sets the *value* and not the column-name.   You should instead define the arguments as:

```
new SelectArg("date", null);
```

To backtrack, the [javadocs for `Where.raw()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#raw%28java.lang.String,%20com.j256.ormlite.stmt.ArgumentHolder...%29) state:

> args - Optional arguments that correspond to any ? specified in the rawStatement. Each of the arguments must have either the corresponding columnName or the sql-type set.

You can also use the `SqlType` constructors as well.  I've improved the Javadocs on `SelectArg` documentation to help with this.  See [this change on github](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/1bf01e69763137149fb014fed7ee64474b218a79).

Also, as I mentioned, I think you want to do something like:

```
SelectArg dateArg = new SelectArg("date", null);
SelectArg endDateArg = new SelectArg("endDate", null);
carsQB.where().raw("CASE WHEN future = true THEN date > ? ELSE endDate > ? END",
    dateArg, endDateArg);
...
dateArg.setValue(...);
endDateArg.setValue(...);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks Gray! But now how do I set the 2 dates arguments?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to address that @MarcoMatarazzi.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: I as a bit off in my answer @MarcoMatarazzi.  Edited.

Comment: to make it work I had to setArgumentHolderValue(0, new Date()) on the prepared query. In fact using the setValue(..) method on the SelectArg object didn't seem to work. What do you think about it? thanks again!

Comment: Can you contact me via the web site @MarcoMatarazzi.  That's doesn't make sense.  http://256.com/gray/email/